# Python caffe interface installation and import

Tags: python, caffe

I am new to `caffe` framework. My understanding is that `caffe` is a tool but it has interface for working in python. Once the interface module (it is called `pycaffe`, right?) is installed, `import caffe` can work. Am I right?

If I am right, can I just install the **caffe interface** for python **without** local installation of **caffe tool**? My friend says that installing caffe is time-consuming and I can use his compilation of caffe. Now when I do `import caffe` in python, the error is `no module named caffe`. But when I searched online for this module installation, it seems people with this problem all have caffe locally installed, and it seems not as easy as to install a module like "numpy" for which you can simple do a `pip install`

Hope I have explained clearly...Anyone can give some instructions?

Comment: How did you use your friend's pycaffe?

Comment: he said including these two lines: `caffe_root = '/path/to/his/caffe/'; sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')'. Any idea?

Comment: @did your friend built pycaffe?

Comment: @Shai I think so as the python script including `import caffe` is given by him. He suggests me to add his caffe path to my PYTHON_PATH and install the pycaffe locally. Now I am following https://iqbalnaved.wordpress.com/2016/05/08/installing-caffe-and-pycaffe-on-ubuntu-14-04/ but don't know how to proceed with `cd /path/to/caffe/folder`